# Can I write a Keycloak Login page with Vue?

Tags: vue.js, keycloak

As far as I know and tried, Keycloak comes with .ftl templates.

I want to use Vue and everything that comes with it, to create a login Page that is visually
consistent with the rest of my application.

Can I do that? If so how?

To Clarify: I know how to protect an application with keycloak, but I want to know how to use Vue for a Keycloak Login page.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible - I would say it's hackish. See POC: https://github.com/jangaraj/vuetify-keycloak-theme/

Comment: I agree on the "hackish" part. Especially, because this project is more about vuetify than vue.

Comment: @telion hackish is because you are mixing keycloak spa with vue spa. Not because vuetify - standard vue developer should be able to delete vuetify part from my poc, so only pure vue part will be used.